# Find element with same class but in the same div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append some content inside a div using its class name.
The event must shoot after user click an  element.

My structure is like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="divOne">
        <div class="divOneItem"><a class="myLink" href="#">CLICK TO APPEND</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTwo">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>CONTENT TO APPEND:</legend>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="divOne">
        <div class="divOneItem"><a class="myLink" href="#">CLICK TO APPEND</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTwo">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>CONTENT TO APPEND:</legend>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Foreach "click to append" link, I would like to append only in its respective "divTwo" a "hello world"

tag!

This code below appends in every "divTwo" div!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myLink').click(function() {
        $(".wrap > .divTwo > fieldset").append( "<p>Test</p>" );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

With your html, you could do something like this for a quick solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myLink').click(function(evt) {
        $(this).closest(".divOne").next().find("fieldset").append( "<p>Test</p>" );
    });
});
```

In my opinion though, this is pretty ugly and prone to lots of issues. If you change the structure of your html even slightly, this is almost guaranteed to break.

`closest(".divOne")` will find the closest node (up the tree) with the class `.divOne`. `next()` will then select your `.divTwo`. Finally, `find("fieldset")` is fairly obvious.

**Solution 2**

There's another option if you're open to adding two small things to your HTML. I added a `data-target` to your append links and gave each fieldset an id. This would allow you some flexibility in updating your HTML in the future. The fieldset is more directly tied to the append link instead of being dependent on the structure of the HTML.

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="divOne">
    <div class="divOneItem">
      <a class="myLink" href="#" data-target="#fieldset1">CLICK TO APPEND</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTwo">
    <fieldset id="fieldset1">
      <legend>CONTENT TO APPEND:</legend>
    </fieldset>
  </div>

  <div class="divOne">
    <div class="divOneItem">
      <a class="myLink" href="#" data-target="#fieldset2">CLICK TO APPEND</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTwo">
    <fieldset id="fieldset2">
      <legend>CONTENT TO APPEND:</legend>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.myLink').click(function(evt) {
    const $target = $(evt.target)
    const fieldset = $target.data("target")
    $(fieldset).append( "<p>Test</p>" );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.myLink').click(function() {
     $(this).parent().next(".divTwo").find("fieldset").append( "<p>Test</p>" );
  });
});
```